# React-Hook-Form define UseFormReturn with Picked fields only on form children component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have a form with Fields defined like that:

```
type FormFields = {
  foo: string,
  bar: string,
}

const form = useForm<FormFields>();
```

And then I want to create a sub component on my form to handle only  a part of those fields.
The sub-component know only some fields ans don't care about others but want to type-check that required fields are present on the form:

```
type FormPickedFields = {
  foo: string,
}
type PickedFieldsProps = {
  form: UseFormReturn<FormPickedFields>
}

const PickedFields = ({ form }: PickedFieldsProps) => {
  return /*...*/ 
};
```

But when I try to use it I have an error

```
const AppForm = () => {
  const form = useForm<FormFields>();
  return (
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(console.log)}>
      <PickedFields form={form} />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Error:

```
Type 'UseFormReturn<FormFields, any, undefined>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormReturn<FormPickedFields>'.
  Types of property 'watch' are incompatible.
    Type 'UseFormWatch<FormFields>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormWatch<FormPickedFields>'.
      Types of parameters 'callback' and 'callback' are incompatible.
        Types of parameters 'info' and 'info' are incompatible.
          Type '{ name?: "foo" | "bar" | undefined; type?: EventType | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ name?: "foo" | undefined; type?: EventType | undefined; }'.
            Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
              Type '"foo" | "bar" | undefined' is not assignable to type '"foo" | undefined'.
                Type '"bar"' is not assignable to type '"foo"'.ts(2322)
```

---

### Solution Tested

#### Repro on CopePen

I tried to reproduce the error on Codepen, but I have no issue here:

https://codepen.io/ArthyFiciel/pen/GRLogYe?editors=1111

I copy/past this code on my VSCode and here I have the same issue..
So I updated my projec to have the same version, but nothing:

- react / react-dom: 18.2
- react-hook-form: ^7.51.0
- TypeScript: 5.1.6 (I tested with 4.9 and 4.1 on my VSCode to be at the same as CodePen but still same issue)

#### Redefine the `form` type

I tested to implement thing like that:

```
export type UseFormReturnPickFields<ElementFormType extends FieldValues, TContext = any> = Omit<UseFormReturn<ElementFormType, TContext>, 'watch' | 'setValue' | 'getValues' | 'register' | 'formState' | 'control' | 'trigger'> & {
  watch: (fieldNames?: Array<FieldPath<ElementFormType>>) => any;
  setValue: (name: FieldPath<ElementFormType>, value: FieldPathValue<ElementFormType, FieldPath<ElementFormType>>, options?: { shouldValidate?: boolean, shouldDirty?: boolean }) => void;
  getValues: (fieldNames?: Array<FieldPath<ElementFormType>>) => Partial<ElementFormType> | FieldPathValue<ElementFormType, FieldPath<ElementFormType>>;
  register: UseFormRegister<ElementFormType>;
  formState: Omit<UseFormReturn<ElementFormType>['formState'], 'errors'> & {
    errors: Partial<Record<FieldPath<ElementFormType>, any>>
  },
  control: Control<ElementFormType, TContext>
}
```

To use it like that

```
type PickedFieldsProps = {
  form: UseFormReturnPickFields<FormPickedFields>
}
```

But it's ugly (I don't like redefining types, in case version change) and it's not working... :/

Do someone have a solution !?